# How to test a server API (REST) including interactions from multiple users/clients with symfony?

Tags: rest, symfony, automated-tests, client-server

We have a supplier that develops a linux-server for us exposing a REST API. We are developing a client application that uses this REST API. Multiple clients running this client applications work together and e.g. have a chat functionality. I would now like to write tests using the rest-API to verify if the server logic for this chat functionality is working: e.g. "Does client Jane receive the correct message if client Tarzan is sending a message".

I am thinking about something like this (pseudo-code):

```
client_tarzan = createclient()
client_jane = createclient()

#the actual login logic is hidden to make the example easier
client_tarzan.login_to_server 
client_jane.login_to_server

client_tarzan->request('POST‘,hello_message_for_jane)
received_message = client_jane->request('GET‘,inbox_path)
expect(received_message).to be(expected_message)
```

The server needs the REST API calls from Tarzan and Jane to be coming from different IP addresses as it internally uses the IP addresses in its logic.

1. Is this possible with synfony?
2. How would I start to do something like that?
3. Do I need to do something special when interfacing the linux server (e.g. run it in a VM?) as I cannot imagine how simfony would be able to create actual TCP packages coming from different IP addresses in order to make the server believe that the two clients are actually separate. I guess this is the core of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony's [test-client](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/testing.html#your-first-functional-test) supports faking IP addresses and you can create multiple clients in a test.

The following example should give you an idea how to get started:

```php
$client1 = static::createClient([], ['REMOTE_ADDR' => '11.11.11.11']);
$client2 = static::createClient([], ['REMOTE_ADDR' => '22.22.22.22']);

$client1->request('POST', '/say', ['message' => 'Hi']);
$client2->request('GET', '/chat');
```

For further guidance please consult the documentation chapter: [Working with the Test Client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the REMOTE_ADDR option. I will have a look into this solution.